# JQuery OnClick show nearest div class not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of buttons and a div under each which I need to show when the user clicks each button.

This is what I'm trying, but nothing is happening.

**jQuery**

```
<script>
         $( document ).ready(function() {
            $(this).click(function() {
                $(this).closest(".mainbutton").show();
            });
         });
</script>
```

**Html**

```
<a class="mainbutton" role="button">click me</a>
 <div class="mydiv" style="display:none;">
   <h1>I was hidden</h1>
 </div>
```

Comment: You are binding events to the document..

Comment: You want to show div direct under the button only single div will show?

Comment: In your Jquery what is mean by $(this) in $(this).click( function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not so sure what you try to achieve but I guess what you would like to do is something like this:

```
 $(".mainbutton").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".mydiv").show();
 });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The `.closest()` method is meant for parent elements. You need to use `.siblings()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(".mainbutton").click(function() {
    $(this).next("div").show();
});
```

`closest()` traverses UP the DOM tree!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".mainbutton").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".mydiv").show();
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that u want

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

        $('.mainbutton').on('click',function() {
               $(this).siblings(".mydiv").show();
        });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exact your requirement but I think you want to do something like this

Please see [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HmyvS/1/)

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {

            $(".mainbutton").click(function() {
                $(this).next(".mydiv").show();
            });

         });
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can simple use this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $(".mainbutton").click(function() {
         $(".mydiv").css("display", "inherit");
       });
    });
```